# What recommended amount of storage for storing timestamps?

Tags: solidity, timestamp

E.g: uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64, uint128, uint256? Which of these is best recommended to future-proof the application? And given each uint, what year is the furthest it could be stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Yellow Paper the block's timestamp is storead as a scalar integer less than 2<sup>256</sup>.

If you do not care about space then an uint256 should be good enough for your future needs.

Ethereum uses the [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) representation for timestamps, you can use an utility like [this](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) to convert integer ranges to dates

- Using uint8 should be good until '1970-01-01T00:04:15+00:00'
- Using uint16 should be good until '1970-01-01T18:12:15+00:00'
- Using uint32 should be good enough until '2106-02-07T06:28:15+00:00'
- Using uint64 should be good for 584,942,417,355 years after 1970